Select contents of next { } when already in another function using Vim
Let's say I'm working in the following file:
int main() {
    foo() {
        // do thing
    }
}

If my cursor is currently sitting anywhere in the text foo, and I want to enter Visual mode, select all text within the body of the Foo function, what commands would I do?
If I use vi{ this will cause the entire contents of the main() {} block to be highlighted (due to it being the enclosing block of my cursor), when all I want is the contents of the foo() {} block (the next block forward from my cursor) to be highlighted.
Is my only option to first use f{ to put my cursor on the { of the foo() {} block before running vi{?

Why don't you want to move your cursor?

@Friedrich If a quicker way exists, I'd like to learn it.

In your example, both j and $ are shorter than f{ :-) You might also be interested in the ]m and ]M motions, as in ]mv]M. Create a mapping if you want to have quick access.

Yes, moving your cursor to the opening { and then doing vi{ (or vi}, or viB) is how you do it, there is no better built-in method. Note that $ would be more efficient than f{ in this case.
If you really don't like that extra motion, you can try target's "next pair" text objects but, honestly, vin{ is only marginally better than $vi{.
